# Text of the label not displayed in browser

Tags: asp.net

i have assigned the value to the label from data table ,the value of label is shown when i checked using break point.But it not shown in the browser

```
if(loadingHubArrivalTable.Rows.Count > 0 && dt != Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01"))
            {
                //ReferenceLabel.Text = loadingHubArrivalAdapter.SelectReferenceNumber(Convert.ToInt32(VehicleDropDownList.SelectedValue)).ToString();
                ReferenceLabel.Text = loadingHubArrivalTable.Rows[0]["ReferenceNumber"].ToString();
                VehicleNumberLabel.Text = VehicleDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
                //loadingHubArrivalTable.Rows[0]["VehicleNumber"].ToString();

                ObjectDataSource1.Select();
                CheckBoxList.DataBind();

            }
```

Comment: Please post your code ...

Comment: when i hover my cursor to the ReferenceLabel.Text it shows the value...But is not displayed in the browser

Comment: is ReferenceLabel an asp:Label control?

Comment: it is asp:label control